# Updating a TextBlock in WPF across pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, modern-ui

I am using a WPF application using the MUI (Modern User Interface) libraries by FirstFloor. I would like to have the option to have an update page where the user is allowed to type in a message or what have you and what they type in the `RichTextBox` will then be updated on the Home.xaml `TextBlock.Text`. I have no idea how to start this. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the question is fairly broad. It would be better if you would provide [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried so far, along with a detailed explanation of what that code does and how it's different from what you want.

Barring that…

The most obvious answer seems to me to be: store the text in a `string` property somewhere, which is bound to both the `RichTextBox` (e.g. to the `Document` property via converter) and the `TextBlock.Text` property.

Assuming the text should be updated only via the `RichTextBox`, you can bind using `OneWayToSource`, and likewise to the `TextBlock.Text` property as `OneWay`. I.e. set up the bindings so that they properly reflect the intended flow of information. Make sure to select the appropriate `UpdateSourceTrigger` value for your scenario (e.g. `LostFocus` or `PropertyChanged`) so that the bound property value is updated according to your needs.

In this way, when the user edits the `RichTextBox`, the backing property will be updated to reflect the user's input, and then will be automatically mirrored to the `TextBox` as desired.

Comment: Honestly I haven't tried anything as I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Then I would suggest starting as I describe above. Once you have some actual code, it will be possible to ask a better, more specific question (or you will just get it working on your own).

Comment: I'll do a little digging to fully understand your answer. I'm self teaching C# and XAML so I don't quit know everything yet lol

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately, to provide from scratch all of the foundational information implied in the above, such as how to correctly set up dependency properties and bind them to UI element properties, would make your question far too broad. It's assumed that you've got some familiarity with the API already.